# Which is suitable for my API serrvice SOAP or REST?

Tags: xml, api, rest, soap, wsdl

I am to build an API system for a booking facility in my site. The key functions are:
1. getData(id)  - to fetch few details of a product from server (data upto 5 fields after little calculation).
2. booking(data array) - send 10-15 fields data to do a registration in the server.

I am confused which API technology to be used,  SOAP-WSDL  or REST ??  Please advise.

The main site is having around 10K visitors daily and expect 50K-70K soon as per the promotions going on.  Also, expecting upto 5K requests through the proposed API integrated by partnering sites.

Whats your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with REST. It's as secure as SOAP (i.e. HTTPS), and the payload is smaller as there  is no SOAP envelope. Also you can choose to use JSON which would make it smaller still, although you could use JSON with SOAP. The REST verbs lend themselves well to what you are trying to do - GET for getting the data, POST for creating the records etc.

There are plenty of references on the Internet that compare the two protocols.